# If error, next iteration in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, iteration, try-catch

I'm looking for a simple way to move on to the next iteration in a for loop in R if the operation inside the for loop errors.

I've recreated a simple case below:

```
for(i in c(1, 3)) {
  test <- try(i+1, silent=TRUE)
  calc <- if(class(test) %in% 'try-error') {next} else {i+1}
  print(calc)
}
```

This correctly gives me the following calc values.

```
[1] 2
[1] 4
```

However once I change the vector in i to include a non-numeric value:

```
for(i in c(1, "a", 3)) {
  test <- try(i+1, silent=TRUE)
  calc <- if(class(test) %in% 'try-error') {next} else {i+1}
  print(calc)
}
```

This for loop doesn't work. I was hoping for the same calc values as above with the vector excluding the non-numeric value in i.

I tried using tryCatch as the following:

```
for(i in c(1, "a", 3)) {
  calc <- tryCatch({i+1}, error = function(e) {next})
  print(calc)
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

Could someone please help me understand how I could achieve this using a for loop in R?

Comment: You might want to examine what `c(1, "a", 3)` actually is.  I think you believe that only the middle element is character but that is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to do this though. Is this a simplified example? If it isn't then just using `as.numeric` on the input vector will make the characters into NA.  Play around with it `as.numeric(c(1, "k", "3")) + 1`

Comment: @Dason I'm actually more interested in error handling of the control flow within the for loop example as this is just a simplified case of a larger script I have. I only violated the definition of vector in i by putting a character element to recreate a scenario that throws out an 'Error'. Hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: The issue you created with your example though is that you created all errors.  You didn't leave a good case.

Comment: What output do you want from this? Do you want a vector of where the errors are, or a vector of the valid results?

Answer (score 1):

As Dason noted, an atomic vector really is not the best way of storing mixed data types. Lists are for that. Consider the following:

```
l = list(1, "sunflower", 3)

for(i in seq_along(l)) {
   this.e = l[[i]]
   test <- try(this.e + 1, silent=TRUE)
   calc <- if(class(test) %in% 'try-error') {next} else {this.e + 1}
   print(calc)
}

[1] 2
[1] 4
```

In other words, your former loop "worked". It just *always* failed and went to next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the "purr" package that might be helpful. 
It goes through your list or vector and returns the elements that will cause errors

```
#Wrap the function you want to use in the adverb "safely" 
safetest <- safely(function(x){ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(x)),
                                  x+1,
                                  as.numeric(x)+1)})

myvect<-c(1,"crumbs",3) #change to list if you want a list

#Use the safe version to find where the errors occur
check <- myvect  %>% 
  map(safetest) %>%
  transpose %>% .$result %>% 
  map_lgl(is_null)

myvect[check]

#This returns the results that did not through an error
#first remove NULL elements then flatten to double.
#The two flatten expresiion can be replaced by a single unlist
myvect  %>% 
  map(safetest) %>%
  transpose %>% .$result %>% 
  flatten()%>%flatten_dbl()
```

see https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/01/06/purrr-0-2-0/ for the original example.